# custom button in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I am trying to use a custom button in Openlayers but is does not work. what am i doing wrong?

```
var custom_button = new Openlayers.Control.Button({
            displayClass: 'olControlCustomButton', 
            trigger: codigo2,
        })

        var control_panel = new Openlayers.Control.Panel({}); 

        control_panel.addControls([
            custom_button
        ])

        map.addControl(control_panel);
```

Comment: It might help if you state how it isn't working and put up a complete code sample, so others can test.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with John Barça that a bit more of your javascript code would be useful or the information which errors you get in your console.

What I can see so far is that you have some typos:

use OpenLayers instad of Openlayers in your var custom_button  and control_panel

and you forgot on semicolon after

```
control_panel.addControls([
            custom_button
        ])
```